# android - RecyclerView onclick manage other items' appearance

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

What is the way to manage *RecyclerView* items other than the **clicked** one when *onItemClick*? (e.g., I have a *shared elements transition* for launching another *Activity* and I'd like to animate "*alpha*" of the other items' root layouts at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

you can put callback interface in your ViewHolder and assign your onClickListener.

ViewHolder

```
    private HomeItemCallback mCallback;

    public interface HomeItemCallback {
        void onHomeClicked(Category category);
    }

public HomeViewHolder(View itemView, HomeItemCallback callback) {

        super(itemView);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

        mCallback = callback;

        gotoButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mCallback != null & mCategory != null){
            mCallback.onHomeClicked(mCategory);
        }
    }
```

And in your MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder.HomeItemCallback {

    @Override
    public void onHomeClicked(Category category) {
        // Change your action according what you want, 
        // in this case animate alpha of other items
    }

}
```

Comment: how can I retrieve other items here to change? (think I just need a one line example)

Comment: On your adapter onBindViewHolder: Category category = mCategories.get(position);
        holder.bindHolder(category);

Comment: So the last line is the thing that will return me any item of my choice?

Comment: do I get it right that Category is the class, objects of which are in my List<>?

Comment: @JustinMcGuire yes, it is a Parcelable object that you can put on an Intent

Comment: so I need to implement Parcelable in that class since I haven't done it yet?

Comment: @JustinMcGuire yes